# How to Customize the Compound field view on UI in lead object?

Tags: salesforcedx, page-layout, salesforcedx-cli, leads, compound-fields

How can I customize the layout compound field name on lead object.
[image]

I want to display my salutation, firstname, lastname, middlename, suffix below Name field label like in below picture

[image]

How can I achieve this. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using OOB settings available in Salesforce with steps as below:

In Classic:

1. Click Setup | Customize | User Interface.
2. In the 'Name Settings' section, deselect **Enable Middle Names for 'Person Names'** and **Enable Name Suffixes for 'Person Names.'**
3. Click Save.

In Lightning Experience:

1. Click the Gear Icon | Setup | User interface | User interface
2. In the 'Name Settings' section, deselect **Enable Middle Names for 'Person Names'** and **Enable Name Suffixes for 'Person Names.'**
3. Click Save

[image]

Output:

[image]

Note: The Middle Name and Suffix fields are available for the following person objects: Contact, Lead, Person Account, and User.

Refer to [article](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000317840&type=1&mode=1)

Comment: i dont want to remove any field .I just want display firstname,l astname,salutaion ,middlename suffixs below Name label .Not at the right handside of Name label

Comment: Try to check with implementation example given over this [link](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/projects/workshop-override-standard-action/override_4)